Did I break my GPU?
I have a Dell Precision T5810 with a hot-swap PSU that connects to a power distribution board. The board has two 10-pin EPS/CPU power connectors. I purchased an "8-Pin EPS / 8-Pin ATX Male to 6+2 Pin PCIe Male Cable" on Amazon. I connected the end labeled "CPU" to one of the 10-pin EPS/CPU connectors, which fit but only used half of the connector. I plugged the other end into the 8-pin PCIe power connector on my RX 6600 GPU.
When I tried to power on the machine, it didn’t start, and the power button blinked amber. I then unplugged the PCIe power cable and tried again—the GPU fans spun up briefly, but the machine shut down immediately afterward. I didn’t notice any smell of burning plastic, and the cable appears undamaged. Could I have damaged my GPU?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

you can answer your question by running a diagnostic test

It's certainly possible that you have damaged your GPU, but the only way to know it by testing the equipment that you have.
